# Is it "dent" or "dint"?

Tags: orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

It seems both *dent* and *dint* can mean an impression or hollow in a surface. Is there a reason for the two spellings? Do they have different connotations?

Comment: It's usually *dent*. I've never heard *dint* used this way, but [here](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a+ding+in+it%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%22a+dint+in+it%22&psj=1&oq=%22a+dint+in+it%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=5359l5726l0l6020l2l2l0l0l0l0l49l86l2l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=67bc8da6351bb1b0&biw=1327&bih=893) are 108 written instances. The variant I've heard quite often is *ding*, but that gets less than 40 hits in Google Books.

Comment: Dent: "ORIGIN Middle English (as a noun designating a blow with a weapon): variant of dint." Oxford Dictionary. So there is no difference AFAIK.

Comment: What did your on-line dictionary sources say?

Comment: @Mohammad: That doesn’t smell like the *OED* — ***this*** does: [dent n.2](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/50037): Etymology:  < French *dent*  tooth; but sense  1  perhaps originated as an extension of sense  4  of **dent** *n.1,* under the influence of the French word, or of indent  and its family. 1. An indentation in the edge of anything; in *pl.* applied both to the incisions and the projections or teeth between them."

Comment: @tchrist: Used this one: "New Oxford American Dictionary 3rd edition © 2010 by Oxford University Press, Inc."

Comment: @Mohammad Similarly, [dint n.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/53072) is "Etymology:  Old English *dynt*, cognate with Old Norse *dyntr*, *dyttr* in same sense; compare Swedish dialect *dunt*. Not recorded in the other Germanic languages. See also **dent** *n.1*  and **dunt** *n.1*  Sense  3  is manifestly influenced by indent  and its family." and including sense "3. A mark or impression made by a blow or by pressure, in a hard or plastic surface; an indentation; = **dent** *n.1* 4". I am getting really sick of these damned general reference questions by people who refuse to use a dictionary.

Comment: @Mohammad Then you should have said all that, citing which dictionary you mean.  "Oxford Dictionary" makes everybody think you mean the real one. It's really misleading.

Comment: There's an American brand of beef stew called [Dinty Moore](http://www.hormelfoods.com/Brands/BrandWall/Dinty-Moore-stew), which played a large part in my childhood nutrition.  Quite often the can would suffer a fall between the store and the stovetop... we called those cans "*Denty* Moore".

Comment: Lovely word, pity it isn't used more often. I've just used it in an article I was translating about cyberspace: "...to maintain total social control that ensures its interests and survival, either through persuasive language or storytelling techniques, as in democracies (subtle totalitarianisms), or by dint of censorship and repression, as in the case of authoritarian governments"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[According to Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dunt), both *dent* and *dint* come from Old English *dynt* (pre-900), which became Middle English *dynt*, *dent*, *dunt*, and *dint*. The short vowel sounds denoted by I and E are in free variation in many English dialects, and have been, so far as I know, for most of English history. Before English spelling was fixed, they would have been spelt freely as well, and thence the minor discrepancy.

All these words originally referred to a blow, kick, or strike, and were gradually extended by analogy till they lost that meaning in most dialects. (*Dunt* is preserved in Scottish.) Both *dent* and *dint* now refer to the *result* of a blow, while *dint*—as in “by dint of”—also refers to means or force.

Also note that we get *indent* (and *indentation*) from a different source: the French *endenter*, to literally “entooth” something by giving it notches or jags. *Dent* in all its forms is much older, and could not have been influenced by *indent*, in case you were curious.

Answer (score 0):

Where I grew up, in Central England, *dent* and *dint* were both in common usage.  They are just variants in pronunciation -- like *scone* (/skɒn/) and *scone* (/skəʊn/) -- but, unlike *scone*, they are also spelled differently.

Answer (score 0):

A *dent* is a large impression in something, for instance when a car has hit a deer and the bonnet is dented. The car would have a *dint* in it if it had been hit by a small stone.